# Extract a .txt file to a .mat file

Tags: database, matlab, text-files

I am working with a publicly available database in which four files are there : They are all .txt documents. How can I put them in a .mat format ? I am giving a simple example:

```
A.txt file
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 1 2 3
4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 9 8
```

So I need to form a matrix with 4 rows and 6 columns. The data in the txt format is separated by 'space' delimiter. The rows are separated by 'newline'. Typically the .txt documents that I will handle will have sizes 130x1000, 3200x58, etc. Can anyone please help me regarding this? The publicly database is available at : [click link](https://sites.google.com/site/christophlampert/data). Please download the dataset under the topic "Multimodal Texture Dataset".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the `.txt` file into MatLab:

```
load audio.txt
```

then save them

```
save audio audio
```

(the first "`audio`" is the "`.mat`" file, the second "`audio`" is the name of the variable stored in it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Its working. Should I close this question ? Because it looks a bit silly.

Comment: What do you mean with "close"'?

Comment: @roni You can accept the answer, or _delete_ your question. I don't see the question so silly. We often see much worse ones :-)

Comment: @roni - Here's one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082981/how-to-sharpen-an-image-without-using-built-in-functions-like-imsharpen-and-fspe - You at least put some effort into describing your question and it is in fact a good question to ask.  Definitely not poor.   The question I linked is God awful and I'm surprised as to why it hasn't been deleted yet.